# Two circuits combine into one old ceramic fuse panel

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, knob-and-tube

I have a 100 amp service in the basement. In it there are two circuits, numbers 2 (15 amp) and 5 (30 amp) that feed an old fuse box/panel on the first floor. The fuse box has 2 fuses per circuit, fuses 1 & 2 are from the 15 amp breaker and there are two wires that come up from the bottom. Those are from the 30 amp breaker.

The fuse panel has 3 circuits that power most of the second and third floor. I know that it gets power from 2 breakers in the basement panel. You have to turn off both to kill all the power to the panel (and all the circuits). And I was able to trace the 15 amp circuit to fuses 1 & 2. This is beyond my skill. I'd like to know first if it's safe.

And then, what I am looking at? Do the 15 and 30 amp circuits combine to 45 amps? I also wonder why there are 2 fuses for every circuit... to protect from a polarity reversal? I am assuming this was done originally to get more amps at the sub-panel without increasing the size of the wire. Maybe. Idk. Any help is appreciated.

Also, this panel runs 2 window A/C units currently, on the 2nd and 3rd floors. I wanted to add a 3rd A/C unit in the baby's room, which is how I opened this particular can of worms.  I circled where the basement circuits connect.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. It's hard to see what you're asking here. What problem are you trying to solve? Please revise to be more specific.

Comment: See those four clips that are clipping onto the feed wires?  Can you tell if there is 120V or 240V between those clips? (e.g. the bottom two clips).   I can't tell if this is the usual 240V subpanel with neutrals hidden, or whether this is a 120V subpanel with neutrals fused.  Also, can you post the nameplates of the air conditioners? We need to know how much power they draw.

Comment: Good call. I didn't even notice the writing on the panel. From what I can tell it reads 0-30A Bryant 250V. But is this rated for or how it's wired. I certainly don't need or want 240 upstairs.

Comment: *the two wires that come up from the bottom are from the 30 amp breaker.* - How are they connected at the 30 amp breaker? Is one wire from the breaker hot terminal and the other wire from the panel neutral bar?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a nice example of knob and tube. It looks like a standard distribution panel to me normally the feeders are the same size because if I understand your explanation

You have 2 feeders that is not unusual, each block is clamped to the hot from your service the neutral usually tied in closer to the branch circuit location.

Is this safe? Yes actually fuses are more reliable than circuit breakers.
A fuse has limitations but if the proper size is used it will always open when the threshold is passed (some breakers are known to be failure prone and even the top brand names have failures rare but it happens).

The reason fuses are not used as much is they need to be replaced when they do there job, what can be less safe is replacing one in the dark, or those that put coins in them because they do not have a spare plus the wiring method and open conductors are not as safe as a modern panel.

Would I update the system to a breaker panel, it depends if it is a registered location you can loose some tax savings by modifying the building different states have different rules and even they have changed in the years I have been an electrician but as a single family residence knob and tube is still code compliant today. And yours appears to be in good shape.

Comment: I'm curious. Why would this panel be getting two feeds from the main breaker box? The blue fuses (circled) are from the 15 amp breaker. The two wires that come in from the bottom (no fuses) are from the 30 amp breaker. Are these adding up to 45 amps in the panel?